# How to find the indices of the elements that exit in another array in numpy?

Tags: numpy

I have two arrays, `a1` and `a2`. `a1` has only unique elements and are sorted, and `a1` has all elements that `a2` has.

```
a1 = np.array([3,4,5,7,8,9])
a2 = np.array([5,3,5,8])
```

I want the output is

```
res = np.array([2,0,2,4])
```

So `a1[res]` == `a2`. How to do it quickly?

Comment: `np.searchsorted(a1,a2)`

Comment: @yatu searchsorted is so far the fastest. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you want this:

```
import numpy as np

a1 = np.array([3,4,5,7,8,9])
a2 = np.array([5,3,5,8])
res = []
for i in a2:
    res.append(*np.where(a1 == i)[0])

res = np.array(res)
print(res)
```

Comment: You might as well just use lists if you're mixing lists and numpy. Numpy is optimized for matrix vectorized operations. If you use it in a loop with single element searches like that this can turn out very inefficient. Also why use all this when there is a single function that does the same?

Comment: You're right. i'm looking for optimization in the code and i'm not very proficient with numpy. Sorry my English is a bit poor.